# Angularjs Select initial value for selectbox inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

**I want to populate the selected color as selected option in selectbox in initially**

link of [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_anil/Y4LZ6/)

here is my partial :

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="QuestionController">
    <ul ng-repeat="product in products">
        <li>
            <div>{{ product.selected | json }}</div>
            <select ng-model="product.selected" ng-options="color.name for color in product.color"></select>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

controller :

```
function QuestionController($scope) {
    $scope.products = [
             {
                "name": "product1", 
                "value": "product1",
                "color": [{ name: 'red',id: 10},{ name: 'Green',id: 11},{name:'Blue',id: 12 }],
                "selected": {name: 'Green', id: 11 }
             },
             {
                "name": "product2",
                "value": "product2",
                "color": [{ name: 'red',id: 10},{ name: 'Green',id: 11},{name:'Blue',id: 12 }],
                "selected": {name: 'red', id: 10 }
             },
             {
                "name": "product3",
                "value": "product3",
                "color": [{ name: 'red',id: 10},{ name: 'Green',id: 11},{name:'Blue',id: 12 }],
                "selected": {name: 'Blue',id: 12 }
            }
        ];    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select ng-model="product.selected" ng-options="color.name for color in product.color track by color.id"></select>
```

Comment: With the "track by" expression, you can instruct angular to use the "id" property in order to consider two objects equivalent instead of using object equality.